# Como criar um relacionamento usando JPA que contenha atributos?

Tags: jpa

Olá, estou trabalhando em um projeto Java Web com Hibernate, Postgres, Glassfish, e uso JPA/JSF. O problema é que meus relacionamentos estavam sendo gerados com a seguinte estratégia:

```
 @JoinTable(name = "prop_user", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "id_prop", referencedColumnName = "idproposicao")}, 
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "id_user", referencedColumnName = "cpf")})
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private UsuarioEntity userProp;
```

Usando o código acima na entidade Usuário, eu criava um relacionamento com a entidade Proposicao, gerando uma tabela de relacionamento, porém não tenho controle sobre esta. Tudo em feito via hibernate pela anotação.

E agora preciso criar um campo extra nesse relacionamento, um atributo "Opiniao" do tipo String e não sei como fazer isso com JPA.

Vi que parece que preciso refazer as relações, pois precisarei criar uma classe entidade para esse relacionamento, moldando manualmente para a minha necessidade. Alguém pode confirmar se estou no caminho certo?

Agradeço!

Answer (score 0):

Sim, esse é o caminho.

Você tem uma classe UsuarioEntity certo? Uma dica, usuário já é uma entidade,e você irá persistir os objetos dessa classe em um banco de dados, para o nome de suas classes ficarem mais enxutas não há necessidade de colocar Entity na frente do nome de sua classe, defina somente como Usuario.

Voltando a sua dúvida, você quer atribuir uma ou várias opiniões para um determinado usuário, nesse caso você cria uma nova classe Opiniao e define os objetos

```
@Entity
public class Opiniao implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long id;
    private String opiniao;

    @ManyToOne //para cada opinião você define o usuário responsável pela opinião
    private Usuario usuario;
....
```

Classe Usuario

```
@Entity
public class Usuario implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long id;
    private String nome;
    ....
```

Nesse caso a relação é um usuário pode ter varias opiniões.

Isso é só um resumo, aconselho você pesquisar mais um pouco, sobre mapeamento JPA, existem bons conteúdos na internet olha esse: [jpa](http://www.thedevelopersconference.com.br/arquivos/TDC2008Floripa-jpa-henrique.pdf) e boas aulas no youtube como essa: [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9rAzAxZ1sXQ)

Comment: Olá Edjane, muito obrigado por sua contribuição. Eu queria atribuir o atributo "opinião" na relação que tenho entre Usuário e Proposição. Estou vendo um exemplo com a anotação [@AssociationOverride](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation/) para mapear a relação com esse campo a mais do que as chaves primárias e estrangeira.